# HTML attributes containing no values

Tags: python, html

I'm currently writing a python HTML parser. When storing attributes and values of tags, I have come across HTML attributes with no assigned value. This is some HTML that I **scraped** off Github, which is when I encountered the error through testing.

```html
<meta name="request-id" content="someRandomValue" data-pjax-transient>

<span class="js-user-status-original-emoji" hidden></span>
```

Since I'm storing attributes as keys in a dictionary, I need a value for the key-value pair. What value does an HTML attribute with no assigned value have? What would the values of "hidden" and "data-pjax-transient" be?

Comment: The value is irrelevant, so you can substitute absolutely anything. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Boolean_Attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have a value, it's just a marker or flag. Logically, you can think of it as a boolean value that's true, if the flag is present, or false otherwise.

Comment: So in the span tag, the 'hidden' attribute would be the same as hidden="True".

Comment: @user5423, the value does not matter. `hidden="True"` or `hidden="lorem ipsum dolor"` means the same thing. As long as the attribute `hidden` exists (with or without a value), it's interpreted as being true. If `hidden` does not exist, then it's interpreted as being false.

Comment: @user5423, in Python, you could store it as a boolean. If you find an attribute without a value, store the attribute name as the key and the boolean `True` as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if there is now value associated with attribute it is considered `true`. 
So in your case 
`<span class="js-user-status-original-emoji" hidden></span>`, 
for attribute `hidden`, you can store true as value.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Attributes with no assigned values](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2) are implicitly given the value of the empty string. However, they are usually used to enable a certain boolean attribute (such as disabling a button). For example,

```js
if (element.dataset.disabled !== undefined) {
    // Prevent user from clicking button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `None` in the dictionary as a value and put an `if` condition in the Python script.